# Throw exception message after insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

I need your help about After Insert Trigger.

I want to throw exception message after insert but insert will not be aborted.

How can i do it? Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_ins` AFTER INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 IF CURDATE() < '2018-08-01' THEN
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'an error message', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1905;
 END IF;
END;
```

EDIT:

*In that case, we can not continue without terminated with 45 sqlstate . And we can see message with "SHOW WARNINGS" statement, right ?*

Comment: What isn't working in your code? Are you getting an error message? If so, edit your question and show the complete text of the error message.

Comment: After looking at the 1st example in [the reference for signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html), I think the value for sqlstate should start with '01'  as a warning. If it starts with '45' it signals an error and the procedure is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

From the ["13.6.7.5 SIGNAL Syntax"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html):

> (...) The `SQLSTATE` value for a `SIGNAL` statement should not start with `'00'` because such values indicate success (...)

and

> (...) `SQLSTATE` values that begin with `'01'` are signals in the warning class. (...)

So try and choose an `SQLSTATE` beginning with `'00'` or `'01'` depending on whether you want to signal a success message or a warning.

Answer (score 0):

sqlstate's starting with 45 are errors and terminate the procedure. sqlstate's starting with 01 are warnings and allow the procedure to continue. Look at
[the reference page for signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) and the first example for more info

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_ins` AFTER INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF CURDATE() < '2018-08-01' THEN
        signal sqlstate '01000' set message_text = 'an error message', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1905;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: In that case, we can not continue without terminated with 45 sqlstate .
And we can see message with "SHOW WARNINGS" statement, right ?